# Cannot run test suite on 2 different browsers using data provider

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I would like to run my selenium test suite which contains 2 tests(test1 and test2) on 2 different browsers.

I want to run the 2 tests in order so i used dependsOnMethods to specify the order

I created a data provider containing the browsers as parameters (i used 2 browser names as strings) but i could not pass it to @BeforeSuite

when i passed the data provider to test1 ,test1 ran 2 times then test2 ran 1 time.

This is not what i need , i need test1 and test2 to run in order on each browser.

Any suggestion how i can achieve this?

Thanks In advance

```
@Test( groups = { "login-positive"},dataProvider="browserList")
public void loginTest(String browser)throws MalformedURLException{

PageUtils.initializeBrowser(browser);
loginPage=     PageUtils.getHomePage().goToLoginPage(PageUtils.getWebDriver());
String username="raghda";
String password="I123123";
loginPage.fillUserName(username);
loginPage.fillPassword(password);
loggedInPage=loginPage.clickSubmit();
 Assert.assertEquals("raghda", loggedInPage.getDisplayedUserName());
}

@Test( groups = { "login-       positive"},dataProvider="browserList",dependsOnMethods= {"loginTest"})
public void ValidateGeneralDonation(String browser)throws    MalformedURLException{


generalDonPage=loggedInPage.clickGeneralDonation();
generalDonPage.selectCharity(1);
generalDonPage.checkDonationItem(0);
assertTrue(generalDonPage.getDonateButton());
```

}

POM.xml

```
 <profile>
 <id>RegressionTest</id>
 <build>
 <plugins>
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.19.1</version>
         <configuration>
                <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test   execution -->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testngregression.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>parallel</name>
                         <value>methods</value>
                     </property>
                    <property>
                         <name>threadCount</name>
                        <value>1</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
     </profile>
    </profiles>
```

testngregression.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
<test name="regression">
<parameter name="loggedIn" value="false"></parameter>
<groups>
  <define name="login-all">
    <include name="login-positive" />
    <include name="login-negative" />
  </define>
  <define name="login-positive-only">
    <include name="login-positive" />
  </define>
  <run>
    <include name="login-positive-only" />
  </run>
</groups>
<classes>
  <class name="basicportal.automation.TestDriver" />
</classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: Hi All,i posted the code but i did not get any feedback.